# Where can the backdrop option for blender 2.82 be found for composition?

Tags: compositing-nodes

please where can I find the backdrop in blender 2.82 I cant seems to find it on the shading tab. I have no idea after reading the documentation https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.82/compositing/properties.html

Comment: That option is for the *Compositor* not the *Shader Editor*.

Comment: @RobertGützkow bless, what is the difference between the shading and compositor tab then?

Comment: in 2,8 they are two different editors, they both use nodes, but for different purposes. Shading is for materials used in the geometry. The compositor deals with rendered images and pixels

Comment: The *Shader Editor* is for creating [materials](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/materials/introduction.html), the *Compositor* for [compositing and editing images](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/introduction.html). Note that the tabs in the header are workspaces, which use these editors in particular areas of the interface.

Comment: @RobertGützkow can you write an answer so that we can up vote it?